# how to repeat a particular Test Method in TestNG which are depent on an other Test Method

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

hi all i have one doubt please help on this

im having this testing code in TestNG in which i have to login -> find the product combination -> fill the form

the code is like this

```
@Test
public static void login(){

// login code

}

@Test(dependsOnMethod = "login")
pubilc find_combination(){

// finding code 

}

@Test(dependsOnMethod = "find_combination")
public static void fill_form(){

// filling the product form

}
```

in this i want to repeat the find_combination and fill_form so that i can create more product request for testing 
i google and found that @Test('invocationCount = 10') will repeat a test method but my question is that i want to execute the login only once 
and repeat the 2nd and 3rd test method 10 time can anyone help me please ... im using Eclipse

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can put your login in beforeClass. This way it would execute only once for all tests in your class.  If login fails, then your tests wouldn't be executed.  Keep the invocation count on the test.